# PHP function fails to connect to the database to call query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have three `.php` files.

db_conx.php

```
$db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin", "gestiune");
    // Evaluate the connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
}
```

functions.php

```
function deplata($pid){
        $sqlp = "SELECT * FROM plati WHERE user_id";
        $queryp = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlp);
        $type = "day";
        $payments = 0;
        $salary = 80;
        $days = 4;
        $topay = 0;
        while($getplata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryp)){
            $plati += $getplata['valoare'];
        }
        if($tip == "day"){
            $topay = $days * $salary;
        }

        return $topay;
}
```

And I have the index.php file to call the files and use them.

```
include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
include_once("php_includes/functii.php");

$salariu = deplata(5);
echo $salariu;
```

The problem is that it will not connect to the database and it returns some errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: db_conx in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\manager\pages\php_includes\functions.php on line 5
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in D:\xampp\htdocs\manager\pages\php_includes\functions.php on line 5
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in D:\xampp\htdocs\manager\pages\php_includes\functions.php
>   on line 11

And then it prints the value (since it does not currently use database any values).
What I tried: I tried to put the `functions.php` content directly into the `index.php` file, I tried to call the `db_conx.php` file inside the `functions.php` file.

Comment: Its not getting `$db_conx` you need to include that file within your functions.php

Comment: your sql statement isn't ok: `"SELECT * FROM plati WHERE user_id=$pid"`

Comment: I tried, this didn't helped. What solved the problem was what @Developing suggested: `global $db_conx;`
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the value the in `function.php`.checkout the below code

***function.php***

```
function deplata($pid){

   global $db_conx;

    $sqlp = "SELECT * FROM plati WHERE user_id";
    $queryp = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlp);
    $type = "day";
    $payments = 0;
    $salary = 80;
    $days = 4;
    $topay = 0;
    while($getplata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryp)){
        $plati += $getplata['valoare'];
    }
    if($tip == "day"){
        $topay = $days * $salary;
    }

    return $topay;
}
```

***index.php***

Check the typo mistake in `index.php`

```
include_once("php_includes/function.php");
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for helping me. I'm a beginner with functions, this helped. I will mark this as winning answer as soon as the website will allow me. Again, thanks!

Comment: The typos were there because I translated the variables and names to English in the post, so you guys can find the logic in my script. In my files they're in Romanian.